# Function Repeater JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to figure out how to make a simple function that will take 2 arguments and return a new string that will repeat the string a certain amount of times that is described in the 2nd argument.

I would like to have it return hellohellohellohellohello but it is only returning hello once.

example:

This is what I have so far, but it only returns hello once

```
function repeat (arg1, arg2)
{
    var counter = 0
    while(counter < arg2)
        return arg1
        counter++

}
repeat("hello", 5);
```

Comment: nice. what have you tried?

Comment: This seems like one of those easily Googled questions.  "js repeat string" has lots of useful results.

Comment: @NinaScholz 

    

function repeat (arg1, arg2)
{
    var counter = 0
    while(counter < arg2)
        return arg1
        counter++

}
repeat("hello", 22);

Comment: Ive tried google. I cant seem to find the one I need. I need something like this..

Comment: function repeat (arg1, arg2)
{
    var counter = 0
    while(counter < arg2)
        return arg1
        counter++

}
repeat("hello", 22);

Comment: how do I put that into a grey code box???

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert to JS but it took me about 10 seconds to find out this already exists.

```
"Hello".repeat(10)
```

Easy.

Comment: Small warning though, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat , it's not yet supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the code because you should try it yourself. But I will give you the logic to how this will work.

```
function(arg1, arg2)
{
    counter = 0
    while(counter < arg2)
        print arg1
        counter++

}
```

Comment: Comments cannot contain newlines.

Comment: IM SORRY. I AM VERY NEW HERE! how do I create a code box? and how do I skip down 1 line im hitting enter but it just submits my comment @SJR59

Comment: @Amy I dont know what that means

Comment: What you just typed is a comment.  This is a comment.  Comments cannot contain newlines.